# Java interface hierarchy and it's methods with bounded type Generics

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface, bounded-types

I have a scenario where I found to build a hierarchy of type as follows:

IComponent (interface) -> AComponent (class)

Here I want IComponent to contain a method exeucte() which would be implemented by all the classes which implement this interface. Now, apart from the component hierarchy I also want a request/response format for all the components so I thought of below things:

IComponentRequest -> AComponentRequest

IComponentResponse -> IComponentResponse

Now I want to declare the execute() method in IComponent in such a way that all the classes which want to implement can follow the request and response classes of the above mentioned request/response hierarchy. Explaining in terms of code, I am currently declaring the method as below:

```
public interface IComponent<IComponentRequest,IComponentResponse> {

    IComponentResponse execute(IComponentRequest request);
}
```

What I actually want is something like :

```
<Any type which implements IComponentResponse> execute(<Any type which implements IComponentRequest> request) {
}
```

I tried using generics like :

```
public interface IComponent<REQUEST,RESPONSE> {}
```

But in these cases I face issue in implementations while calling methods and receiving responses that REQUEST and RESPONSE are not any particular java types. Hence, I again went on to use the proper interfaces IComponentRequest and IComponentResponse but there I am not able to apply bounded generics.

Can someone please help on what am I missing here ?

Comment: (1) It is not customary in Java to use `I` for interfaces; we have IDEs now. (2) Be careful that you're not reinventing standard-library API; this looks like a clone of `Function`. (At a minimum, _extend_ `Function` so that your custom implementations can be used with all the existing infrastructure.)

Answer (score 2):

When you specify the generic name, you can also specify type information. Here, you want `extends` for each appropriate type. Something like

```
public interface IComponent<REQUEST extends IComponentRequest,
            RESPONSE extends IComponentResponse> {
    RESPONSE execute(REQUEST request);
}
```

Comment: I suggest using either `<T,R>` or `<I,O>` as more idiomatic than OP's type variables.

Comment: @Elliot Frisch: This helps. the overriden method though in my implementation class comes as 

`public IComponentResponse execute(IComponentRequest request)`
I am now using specific typecasting to get to child classes of request and response types.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- using <T,R> or <I,O> actually generates overriden method as : 
`public R execute(T request)` . How do you propose to declare the sub-class and it's methods while implementing the interface ? 
I mention some examples here : 
`public class AComponent<AComponentRequest,AComponentResponse> implements IComponent<T,R>{`

And the clients calling the implemented component method will then have to receive `T` and `R` generic types. Should we use explicit typecasting then in those cases ?

Comment: @RaviRaiSharma Don't re-declare new type parameters in your class definition. It looks like you need to review the basics of generics; read [the official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) and inspect the declarations of the classes in the Collections API (in `java.util`).